# How can I change background on mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've a simple page and I would like to change the background image image using mounter enter at buttons. I got three buttons at background.

Problem is that, I want to add fadeIn/fadeOut effect, what I did(I add transition: 1.5s in CSS). But then, when I move too fast between buttons, the fadein/out effect doesn't work properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var svatba = $(".svatbauvod");
  var promo = $(".promouvod");
  var after = $(".afteruvod");
  var pozadi = $(".uvod-body");

  svatba.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod1.jpg)');
  });

  promo.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod2.jpg)');
  });

  after.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod3.jpg)');
  });
});
```

```css
.uvod-body {
  background-image: url("/img/uvod1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <main class="uvod-body">
      <div class="uvod-back">
          <h1><a href="#" class="svatbauvod">Svatební videa</a></h1>
          <h1><a href="#" class="promouvod">Promo videa</a></h1>
          <h1><a href="#" class="afteruvod">After movie</a></h1>

      </div>
   </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the images to classes and use jQuery to change which of these classes is active, you can use the native CSS transitions to achieve your effect.

Here is a sample. I do not have access to the images you are referencing, so I've used colors instead. The fade effect is the same.

Notice that we are using [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/). You can add or remove multiple classes at a time by specifying them in a space-delimited string.

I have applied one of the classes to the element to start. This is similar to the `background-image` property you had applied.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var svatba = $(".svatbauvod");
  var promo = $(".promouvod");
  var after = $(".afteruvod");
  var pozadi = $(".uvod-body");

  svatba.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('uvod1').removeClass('uvod2 uvod3');
    //.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod1.jpg)');
  });

  promo.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('uvod2').removeClass('uvod1 uvod3');
    //.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod2.jpg)');
  });

  after.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('uvod3').removeClass('uvod1 uvod2');
    //.css('background-image', 'url(img/uvod3.jpg)');
  });
});
```

```css
.uvod-body {
  /* background-image: url("/img/uvod1.jpg"); */
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.uvod1 {
  /* background-image: url("/img/uvod1.jpg"); */
  background-color: red;
}

.uvod2 {
  /* background-image: url("/img/uvod2.jpg"); */
  background-color: green;
}

.uvod3 {
  /* background-image: url("/img/uvod3.jpg"); */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <main class="uvod-body uvod1">
      <div class="uvod-back">
          <h1><a href="#" class="svatbauvod">Svatební videa</a></h1>
          <h1><a href="#" class="promouvod">Promo videa</a></h1>
          <h1><a href="#" class="afteruvod">After movie</a></h1>
      </div>
   </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the background directly but styling should be done with CSS for the most part - so we can trigger a class instead (or set a property that "CSS detects").
Here I use color for demonstration but also your background and then toggle the classes depending upon which you hover - the grandparent has the transition you stated and this works.

I added a set of `-two` classes for the `:hover` you see in the CSS just to show that - but that is the element not its grandparent. (no transition there but you could add it in the CSS as you do the grandparent - but that is not really your question.

Note there is a CSS `:has()` to address the "parent" but it is not widely supported as of this writing.

```js
$(function() {
  let svatba = $(".svatbauvod");
  let promo = $(".promouvod");
  let after = $(".afteruvod");
  let pozadi = $(".uvod-body");

  svatba.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('svatbauvod-in')
      .removeClass('promouvod-in afteruvod-in');
  });

  promo.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('promouvod-in')
      .removeClass('svatbauvod-in afteruvod-in');
  });

  after.on('mouseenter', function() {
    pozadi.addClass('afteruvod-in')
      .removeClass('svatbauvod-in promouvod-in');
  });
});
```

```css
.uvod-body,
.uvod-body-two {
  background-image: url("/img/uvod1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: auto;
  outline: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.uvod-body.svatbauvod-in,
.svatbauvod-two:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/uvod1.jpg");
  background-color: #ddffff;
}

.uvod-body.promouvod-in,
.promouvod-two:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/uvod2.jpg");
  background-color: #ffddff;
}

.uvod-body.afteruvod-in,
.afteruvod-two:hover {
  background-image: url("/img/uvod3.jpg");
  background-color: #ffffdd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <main class="uvod-body">
    <div class="uvod-back">
      <h1><a href="#" class="svatbauvod">Svatební videa</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#" class="promouvod">Promo videa</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#" class="afteruvod">After movie</a></h1>
    </div>
  </main>
  <main class="uvod-body-two">
    <div class="uvod-back-two">
      <h1><a href="#" class="svatbauvod-two">Svatební videa</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#" class="promouvod-two">Promo videa</a></h1>
      <h1><a href="#" class="afteruvod-two">After movie</a></h1>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```